# Como instalar módulos em C++

Tags: c++, importação

Gostaria de saber como faço para instalar novos módulos no C++. Por exemplo, recentemente descobri que existe um módulo que tem uma aplicação do método `format` de strings bem parecida com o método de mesmo nome no python (aqui o [link](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) para o módulo). Ocorre que não tenho tido sucesso na importação desse módulo. Segue abaixo um exemplo replicável do meu erro:

```
#include <iostream> //Já tem
#include <string> // Já tem
#include <fmt/format.h> // Preciso instalar. Como??

using namespace std;

int main(){
   string firstname = "Carlos";
   string secondname = "Drummond";
   string thirdname = "de Andrade";

   cout<<fmt::format("{} {} {} foi um grande poeta nascido em Itabira ", firstname, secondname, thirdname)<< endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Eu pesquisei um pouco e vi que para esses módulos externos funcionarem eu preciso ter no meu computador uma pasta com arquivos de extensão `lib` e `h`. Parece que esses arquivos estão no repositório do módulo no Github, então eu baixei todos os arquivos do repositório e tentei rodar o programa, mas não obtive sucesso. Tenho então, duas dúvidas:

1. Eu preciso especificar o `path` para o módulo ser ativado? Se sim, como faço isso?
2. Existe uma forma menos "manual" de fazer isso (em outras palavras, existe algo parecido com o `pip install` do python?

Comment: Já tentou fazer um env no linux, e ver se tem sudo apt?

Comment: env que você diz é um `virtual environment'`? Em relação ao `sudo apt` você está perguntando se existe uma forma de instalação com esse comando? Bom, eu procurei e não encontrei um `sudo apt` para esse pacote. Mas normalmente é assim que se faz? Como se eu estivesse instalando qualquer programa em meu PC?

Answer (score 0):

A maioria dos pacotes e bibliotecas não precisa ser baixada e instalada manualmente no Ubuntu. Você pode instalar o libfmt-dev usando o repositório "universe" oficial, usando o apt.

Execute os seguintes comandos para instalar:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

A maioria dos pacotes do tipo "build" nos repositórios do Ubuntu tem o sufixo "dev" no final. 9 em cada 10 vezes, quando você precisar instalar algum pré-requisito ou dependência para criar coisas usando g ++ ou C ++, esses serão os pacotes "lib" necessários.

Para procurar pacotes disponíveis, você pode usar o comando `apt-cache` search como neste exemplo:

```
apt-cache search libfmt
```

Se você obtiver muitos resultados, poderá filtrar a pesquisa utilizando o comando `grep`:

```
apt-cache search libfmt | grep dev
```

ou:

```
apt-cache search fmt | grep 'C+'
```

ou você pode usar a *flag* -i com grep para que não faça distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas assim:

```
apt-cache search fmt | grep -i 'c+'
```

> **IMPORTANTE:** Essa resposta é uma tradução livre de uma solução obtida pelo autor da pergunta no ask.ubuntu. A versão original pode
>   ser vista nesse [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205765/c-fmt-library-instalation-is-not-working). Optei por postar a tradução para
>   disponibilizar um material em português para que alguém sem domínio da
>   língua inglesa possa ter acesso ao material caso incorra em problema
>   semelhante. Caso esse procedimento viole as regras e convenções do site de alguma maneira, favor me informar que apago a pergunta.